# Explanation for blue stuff in Github Desktop merge conflict?

Tags: merge, github-for-mac, github-desktop

I'm confused with how to use GitHub Desktop when there is a merge conflict. I assumed the blue stuff on the side tells you what lines you want to keep in the merge.  The picture shows the type of blue stuff I'm talking about. 
[image: the blue stuff]
  I selected the parts I wanted to keep, but afterwards, it told me I still had changes to commit.  I thought I had to commit again or something, and then I got both version of the merge inside my file, and had to manually fix it.  So, does selecting the blue just stage it?  Is there a way to resolve the merge conflicts within the GitHub Desktop application, or do I have to open a text editor to resolve the conflict?